# Unpacking tuple directly into class in scala

Tags: scala, iterable-unpacking

Scala gives the ability to unpack a tuple into multiple local variables when performing various operations, for example if I have some data

```
val infos = Array(("Matt", "Awesome"), ("Matt's Brother", "Just OK"))
```

then instead of doing something ugly like

```
infos.map{ person_info => person_info._1 + " is " + person_info._2 }
```

I can choose the much more elegant

```
infos.map{ case (person, status) => person + " is " + status }
```

One thing I've often wondered about is how to directly unpack the tuple into, say, the arguments to be used in a class constructor. I'm imagining something like this:

```
case class PersonInfo(person: String, status: String)
infos.map{ case (p: PersonInfo) => p.person + " is " + p.status }
```

or even better if `PersonInfo` has methods:

```
infos.map{ case (p: PersonInfo) => p.verboseStatus() }
```

But of course this doesn't work. Apologies if this has already been asked -- I haven't been able to find a direct answer -- is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you can get to the methods at least in Scala 2.11.x, also, if you haven't heard of it, you should checkout [The Neophyte's Guide to Scala Part 1: Extractors](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html).

The whole 16 part series is fantastic, but part 1 deals with case classes, pattern matching and extractors, which is what I think you are after.

Also, I get that `java.lang.String` complaint in IntelliJ as well, it defaults to that for reasons that are not entirely clear to me, I was able to work around it by explicitly setting the type in the typical "postfix style" i.e. `_: String`. There must be some way to work around that though.

```
object Demo {

   case class Person(name: String, status: String) {
      def verboseStatus() = s"The status of $name is $status"
   }

   val peeps = Array(("Matt", "Alive"), ("Soraya", "Dead"))

   peeps.map {
     case p @ (_ :String, _ :String) => Person.tupled(p).verboseStatus()
   }

}
```

UPDATE:

So after seeing a few of the other answers, I was curious if there was any performance differences between them. So I set up, what I think might be a reasonable test using an Array of 1,000,000 random string tuples and each implementation is run 100 times:

```
import scala.util.Random

object Demo extends App {

  //Utility Code
  def randomTuple(): (String, String) = {
    val random = new Random
    (random.nextString(5), random.nextString(5))
  }

  def timer[R](code: => R)(implicit runs: Int): Unit = {
    var total = 0L
    (1 to runs).foreach { i =>
      val t0 = System.currentTimeMillis()
      code
      val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
      total += (t1 - t0)
    }
    println(s"Time to perform code block ${total / runs}ms\n")
  }

  //Setup
  case class Person(name: String, status: String) {
    def verboseStatus() = s"$name is $status"
  }

  object PersonInfoU {
    def unapply(x: (String, String)) = Some(Person(x._1, x._2))
  }

  val infos = Array.fill[(String, String)](1000000)(randomTuple)

  //Timer
  implicit val runs: Int = 100

  println("Using two map operations")
  timer {
    infos.map(Person.tupled).map(_.verboseStatus)
  }

  println("Pattern matching and calling tupled")
  timer {
    infos.map {
      case p @ (_: String, _: String) => Person.tupled(p).verboseStatus()
    }
  }

  println("Another pattern matching without tupled")
  timer {
    infos.map {
      case (name, status) => Person(name, status).verboseStatus()
    }
  }

  println("Using unapply in a companion object that takes a tuple parameter")
  timer {
    infos.map { case PersonInfoU(p) => p.name + " is " + p.status }
  }
}

/*Results
  Using two map operations
  Time to perform code block 208ms

  Pattern matching and calling tupled
  Time to perform code block 130ms

  Another pattern matching without tupled
  Time to perform code block 130ms

  WINNER
  Using unapply in a companion object that takes a tuple parameter
  Time to perform code block 69ms
*/
```

Assuming my test is sound, it seems the unapply in a companion-ish object was ~2x faster than the pattern matching, and pattern matching another ~1.5x faster than two maps. Each implementation probably has its use cases/limitations.

I'd appreciate if anyone sees anything glaringly dumb in my testing strategy to let me know about it (and sorry about that var). Thanks!

Comment: Totally works -- this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: You don't need the `unapply`.

Comment: Also, I don't see how `case p @ (_ :String, _ :String) => Person.tupled(p).verboseStatus()` is any better than `case (name, status) => Person(name, status).verboseStatus`

Comment: @Dima indeed the unapply is unnecessary, edited. Also to your other point, it occurs to me that case `p @ (_, _)` is actually enough and scala is smart enough at compile time to warn you if it is not an Array[(String, String)] and you can also dispense with the variable binding operator altogether. One difference then, say for example your case class is something more like `case class Person(name: String, status: String, age: Int, occupation: String)`. Then on the right side of the pattern match your constructor would grow, though this might be better if the order of the tuple is wrong.

Comment: why so much unnecessary code and unclear code? `infos.map(PersonInfo.tupled).map(_.verboseStatus())` all what you need and without any problem with constructor growing.

Comment: Actually, leaving `unapply` in there, combined with Alexey's syntax is ultimately what I really wanted. I posted an answer unifying elements of this answer and the others

Answer (score 4):

The extractor for a case class takes an instance of the case class and returns a tuple of its fields. You can write an extractor which does the opposite:

```
object PersonInfoU {
  def unapply(x: (String, String)) = Some(PersonInfo(x._1, x._2))
}

infos.map { case PersonInfoU(p) => p.person + " is " + p.status }
```

Comment: This is the missing piece in the other answers... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tuppled` for case class

```
val infos = Array(("Matt", "Awesome"), ("Matt's Brother", "Just OK"))

infos.map(PersonInfo.tupled)

scala> infos: Array[(String, String)] = Array((Matt,Awesome), (Matt's Brother,Just OK))

scala> res1: Array[PersonInfo] = Array(PersonInfo(Matt,Awesome), PersonInfo(Matt's Brother,Just OK))
```

and then you can use `PersonInfo` how you need

Comment: The `tupled` thing is crucial! Looks like Ahmad got it all fully worked out, but this was right on.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this (scala 2.11.8):

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class PersonInfo(p: String)

Seq(PersonInfo("foo")) map {
    case p@ PersonInfo(info) => s"info=$info / ${p.p}"
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class PersonInfo
res4: Seq[String] = List(info=foo / foo)
```

Methods won't be possible by the way.

Comment: Hmmm this looks promising but it doesn't work for me, I get: 

    `constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
         found   : PersonInfo
         required: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)`

I have scala version 2.9.2, could it be a version issue? Can you direct me to any relevant docs?

Comment: I don't know about 2.9. I have updated my example with an exact copy from the repl.

Comment: I think I see where you were going now. Ahmad got it all worked out but thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Several answers can be combined to produce a final, unified approach:

```
val infos = Array(("Matt", "Awesome"), ("Matt's Brother", "Just OK"))

object Person{

  case class Info(name: String, status: String){
    def verboseStatus() = name + " is " + status
  }

  def unapply(x: (String, String)) = Some(Info(x._1, x._2))

}

infos.map{ case Person(p) => p.verboseStatus }
```

Of course in this small case it's overkill, but for more complex use cases this is the basic skeleton.